# "If the earth exploded tomorrow" or "If the earth were to explode tomorrow" or "If the earth would explode tomorrow"?

Tags: subjunctives

I basically understand the subjunctive mood.  You use the past tense when you refer to something that is not true in the present.  But which one of the three below would you choose when you refer to something very unlikely to happen in the future?

1. What would you do if the earth exploded tomorrow?
2. What would you do if the earth were to explode tomorrow?
3. What would you do if the earth would explode tomorrow?

I often hear them say "were to" to refer to an unlikely future, but I wonder if the sentence 1 is also OK.  If it is, is there any difference between 1 and 2?  I have also heard "would" in an if-clause even though it is not quite often. I would like to know what difference there is between 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: For what I was said, a sentence like *If I were rich, I would live on Long Island.* essentially means *I will never be rich and I will never live on Long Island.* For the first sentence, I think that the Past Tense would not be used for an event in the future.

Comment: The 3rd example sounds like something a non-native English speaker would say. I would consider it a mistake. The others are fine. The first is colloquial/less formal.